Upload a ssl certificate and it gets deleted ( Nginx/K8s)
Some background:
our application is running in Kubernetes( GCP ).
Ingress is configured via Nginx Ingress controller\Cert-manager.
Issue:
there was a ssl certificate applied and it was in valid state.
I needed to add a new DNS to the certificate. So i downloaded the ssl secret.
Using certbot I manually generated  new cert and priv key ( with existing and new  dns). I deleted the current ssl cert in order to start the renewal process. This step some how caused the deletion of the secret too.
When I apply the sll secret in nginx ns, the secret is immediately being deleted.
GCP logs show that the "kube-system:generic-garbage-collector" is deleting the secret.
I stopped the cert-manager just to make sure its not deleting the cert. Tried applying the secret and still it got deleted.
I expect the secret to be created and the certificate to go into effect.

The issue is occurring because Cert-Manager is managing the SSL certificate secret and deleting it when the secret doesn't align with the Certificate resource it is supposed to manage.
Solution:

Recreate the Certificate Resource:

Cert-Manager relies on the Certificate resource to manage the SSL secret. You need to recreate the Certificate resource with the updated DNS names and reference the secret. This will trigger Cert-Manager to generate and store the correct certificate and private key in the secret.
Example YAML:
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: my-app-cert
  namespace: <your-namespace>
spec:
  secretName: my-app-tls-secret
  dnsNames:
  - existing.example.com
  - new.example.com
  issuerRef:
    name: <your-issuer-name>
    kind: ClusterIssuer




Avoid Manual Changes to the Secret:

Cert-Manager is responsible for managing certificates and secrets. Manual changes or deletion of the secret (e.g., using Certbot) can cause issues as it may not match the state expected by Cert-Manager. Let Cert-Manager handle the renewal and updates automatically.


Verify with Cert-Manager:

Ensure that Cert-Manager is correctly handling the certificate renewal by checking its logs:
kubectl logs -n cert-manager deploy/cert-manager


Check the status of the Certificate resource to see if the new certificate is being issued:
kubectl describe certificate <certificate-name>




Verify Garbage Collection:

The garbage collector in Kubernetes will clean up resources that are not associated with any active resource (like a Certificate resource). Ensure that the Certificate is linked to the correct secret name and namespace.



By ensuring the Certificate resource is applied, Cert-Manager will manage the secret properly, and the certificate should be renewed correctly.
